# scraping e-commerce website using scrapy concept

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to this scrapy concept. I have written a script for E-commerce website and need to scrape below mentioned details in that website. I facing issue with this script. please anyone help me to get out from this issue.

website:https://savedbythedress.com/collections/maternity-tops

```
import scrapy    

class DressSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dress'
    allowed_domains = ['savedbythedress.com']
    start_urls = ['https://savedbythedress.com/collections/maternity-tops']

    def parse(self, response):
        #scraped all product links
        domain = "https://savedbythedress.com"
        link_products = response.css('div[class="product-info-inner"] ::attr(href)').get()
        for link in link_products:
            product_link = domain + link   
            yield{
                'product_link': product_link.css('div[class="product-info-inner"] ::attr(href)').get(),
            }      
            yield scrapy.Request(url=product_link, callback=self.parse_contents)

    def parse_contents(self, response):
        #scrape needed information
        productlink = response.url
        yield{
            'product_title' : response.css('.sbtd-product-title ::text').get(),
            'product_price' : response.css('.product-price ::text').get(),
            'product_review' : response.css('.Natsob ::text').getall()
        }
```

Comment: use yield response.follow(page_url, self.parse_contents)
it will work for you to go to the product page url

Answer (score 0):

use `yield response.follow(page_url, self.parse_contents)` it will work for you

```
import scrapy    

class DressSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dress'
    allowed_domains = ['savedbythedress.com']
    start_urls = ['https://savedbythedress.com/collections/maternity-tops']

    def parse(self, response):
        #scraped all product links
        domain = "https://savedbythedress.com"
        # link_products = response.css('div[class="product-info-inner"] ::attr(href)').get()
        for link in response.css('div.product-info'):
            page_url = link.css('div[class="product-info-inner"] ::attr(href)').get()
            print('PAGE URL IS ', page_url)
            yield response.follow(page_url, self.parse_contents)

            # product_link = domain + link   
            # yield{
            #     'product_link': link.css('div[class="product-info-inner"] ::attr(href)').get(),
            # }      
            print(page_url)
            # yield scrapy.Request(response.follow(page_url), callback=self.parse_contents)

    def parse_contents(self, response):
        print()
        #scrape needed information
        print(response.url)
        productlink = response.url
        yield{
            'product_title' : response.css('.sbtd-product-title ::text').get(),
            'product_price' : response.css('.product-price ::text').get(),
            'product_review' : response.css('.Natsob ::text').getall()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Samsul!